# How to send a BLOB object (image) via containers in a CICS Web Service to the calling Client

Tags: containers, wsdl, blob, cics

I need to send some set of images (stored in DB2 table as BLOB) in the response XML of a CICS Web Service. I'm implementing the web service using WSDL, IGOR (Wrapper and coordinator) and AOR program. Could you please tell how to pass the images to the response and whether we can send only one image or many images?

We have used MQ to send and retrieve the images but via CICS Web Service it is something new.

Answer (score 1):

When the WSDL was converted to a language structure using DFHWS2LS each binary field would have been represented by a container.  Simply populate a binary container with the BLOB data and put its name in the relevant field in the response structure.

You will want to enable MTOM/XOP support for the provider PIPELINE to minimise the amount of data being sent.  See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/6.1?topic=infrastructure-support-mtomxop-optimization-binary-data in the CICS documentation.

You can send multiple BLOBs in the response if that is what is defined in the WSDL.